# Event with team registration

Tags: civievent

How do I create a fee for a team event without each team member being charged? ie one team costs $100 not $100 per person.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with it being on the honor system (you can always check to be sure each team has a paying member), then create 2 Fee Labels 1) Team $100 2)Team Member $0. The teams will have to be sure that one member checks the Team Fee and the rest check Team Member.

It might make it easier if you check the box "Register Multiple Participants" It is under the Online Registration tab of the Event Setup. Then one team member can register the entire team and be sure that they pay the $100 only/at least once.

Note: This is on the honor system since all team members can select the $0 option. But you can check to be sure that they have paid before the event.

Comment: Does this need to mention that this involves "using a Price Set"

Comment: With jQuery on a .extra template you can hide the $0 option on the initial person registering and then hide the $100 for the additional registrations. They run on different templates so you would need a custom template for each.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Drupal or Backdrop, you can set this up using the `webform_civicrm` module. The webform can take team info and multiple team members info simultaneously and only charge the fee one time while also registering all contacts for the same event (that is a setting in the `webform_civicrm` interface).

At the same time, you can add relationship links in the webform to link all the contacts with a custom relationship (for example, "Team Member of/Team Member is" or something along those lines).